# Writing a table to csv file in Matlab

Tags: export-to-csv, matlab-table

I have a table. A sample of a cell is as below:

```
var = [1 16 18 17; 1 10 15 6; 78 10 26 43; 9 13 91 4; 1 17 81 23];
```

I also want to add the column id to this like below:

```
id=[1;1;1;1;1];
```

Now i want to create a table by concatenating id column with var:

```
t = table(id,var)
```

When i try to write it to a csv file with the following syntax:

```
csvwrite(t,'filename.csv','Delimiter',',')
```

I get error like this:

```
Error using csvwrite 
FILENAME must be a character vector.
Error in untitled 
csvwrite(t,'filename.csv','Delimiter',',')
```

How can i write it to a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this instead of csvwrite:

```
writetable(t,'filename.csv')
```

For more info check [this](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writetable.html).

Comment: `writetable` is as slow as a wet week (everything table-oriented in MATLAB is a case study in poor performance - almost as bad as `xlsread`() and `xlswrite`(), which take **4 seconds** to do _anything at all_). For smallish tables (20 x 4) `writetable` takes **5 times** as long as simply joining columns with `'","'`, joining rows with `'\n'` , and `fprintf`-ing the result to a valid, open fileID. (The result will have no opening or closing double-quotes, but even Excel will parse it).